# checking each div in page and change value according to the data in the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

i have buttons created via display suite(the buttons contain 'join' text i need to run the function check to see the value should be join or leave.
you can find my js code and my check function code. my problem is i think im calling the function the wrong way.

```
function init() {
$('div').each(function(){
  $ajax('checkteam')
   .then(function(){
     if (res.data === true){
        var button = $(this).find('.button.pulse');
        $(button).text === 'Leave';
        $(button).data('leave', true);
     }
     else {
          }
        }       
   )  
})
}

'checkteam' => array(
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'page callback' => 'card_generator_check_team_ajax',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
),


function card_generator_check_team_ajax($term_name) {
global $user;
$term = reset(taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name));
$tid = $term->tid;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$arrlength = (sizeof(($user_fields->field_teams[und])));
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
$mytid = ($user_fields->field_teams[und])[$x]['tid'];
if ($tid == $mytid){
return true;
}
return false;
 }
}
```

i need to get the data from checkteam function and if its true then the value should be leave.

Comment: In the `then` callback, you receive the ajax response. `.then(function(){` should be `.then(function(res){`.

Comment: Doesn't make sense sending request for each div when no data is sent. Means all requests are identical and therefore redundant having multiple requests

Comment: @charlietfl each div contain different teams so i need to check each team !

Comment: @randomSoul i tried 
    function init() {
    $('div').each(function(){
      $ajax('checkteam')
       .then(function(res){
         if (res.data === true){
            var button = $(this).find('.button.pulse');
nothing appears i am not sure when i put $ajax('checkteam') i have nothing and when i use $ajax('/checkteam') i have this in the console '[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 43ms'
            $(button).text === 'Leave';
            $(button).data('leave', true);
         }

Comment: Fine but if you don't send team specific data to server it doesn't make sense. You aren't sending anything in what is shown. Beyond that you really haven't identified what the specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl yes i am not sending im just comparing which teams is the user enrolled in and then return true or false if he is enrolled ('true') i change the button text to leave

Comment: But each button is different so each request should be different (by changing url or sending data)...otherwise make one request for all

Comment: @charlietfl how is each button is different i dont see your point but i will explain you more.
i have a div contain title image and button this div repeat itself as the shown picture. the button is the same generated by display suite.
https://ibb.co/mR02dCR

Comment: Ok...then if there isn't a difference then make one request ( not in `each` loop) and update all buttons based on that single request response

Comment: i have edited my answer and added a picture

Comment: OK...then what is the specific problem? You have not identified what it is or any errors that occur or what is happening that shouldn't be happening etc. Take a few minutes to read [ask]. Also haven't explained why you need multiple identical requests ( one for each div)

Comment: the problem is that my ajax not calling the function i dont know whats wrong exactly nothing is happening the buttons aren't changing value.
because each div contain different team  ? and the function check take the termname from the div !

Comment: @charlietfl i am not sure if my ajax is receiving the return of my php function.

Comment: So inspect the actual requests in browser dev tools network to see what status is and what gets returned in response body

Comment: i think the function init is not even triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved! the php function was wrong.

```
function card_generator_check_team_ajax($term_name)
{
  global $user;
  $term = reset(taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name));
  $tid = $term->tid;
  $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

  $arrlength = (sizeof(($user_fields->field_teams[und])));
  for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    $mytid = ($user_fields->field_teams[und])[$x]['tid'];
    if ($tid == $mytid) {
      $arr = 'true';
      continue;
    }
  }
  drupal_json_output($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post looks like a crazy mix of PHP and JavaScript. Here are some basic changes I might suggest.

```
  $("div", context).each(function(i, el) {
    var termName = $(".field-name-title .field-item", this).text().trim();
    $.get(Drupal.settings.setProject.ajaxUrlcheck + "/" + termName,
      function(res){
        if (res === "false") {
          $(".button.pulse", el).html("Leave");
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

`.each()` iterates each element, so you can get the index and element. You can use `$(el).find('.button.pulse')` or you can use `$(".button.pulse", el)` to select the proper elements in jQuery.

Comment: what is the use of i in each(function(i, el)

Comment: @FirasAyari I didn't use it yet it is the Index of each of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code right now but it has one issue which is always execute onetime and not for each (views-row). i will attach my layout in picture.  [image: this is my layout]

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.card_generator = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.views-row', context).each(function(){
       var button = $(this).find('.button.pulse'),
      termName = $(this).find('.field-name-title .field-item');

        $.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.setProject.ajaxUrlcheck + '/' + 
$(termName).text(), 
            method: "GET",
          })
                     .then(function(res){
         if (res === 'true'){
        $(button).text('Leave');            
                     }

    }
            )  
    })
}
};
})(jQuery);
```